# How to preview a Composable with non-null type parameters?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun VerifyScreen(
    email: String,
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator
) {
// .. 

}


@Composable
@Preview
fun VerifyScreenPreview() {
    VerifyScreen("you@re.awesome", null)
}
```

> Null can not be a value of a non-null type DestinationsNavigator

Of course you can change the type by adding a question mark, but what if that is not an option?

```
navigator: DestinationsNavigator?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EmptyDestinationsNavigator` provided by the library

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun VerifyScreenPreview() {
    VerifyScreen("you@re.awesome", EmptyDestinationsNavigator)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's discouraged to pass `NavController` or anything like that to your Composables, see [the decumentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing).
If you follow the recommendation, you will simply pass empty lambda (or more of them) from your `Preview`

> Pass lambdas that should be triggered by the composable to navigate, rather than the NavController itself.

The problem with that is when you need a lot of lambdas in your Composable, it doesn't look very nice. One option then is not to preview such a big Composable as a whole but rather preview some smaller pieces of the ui. The other option would be to create some interface for the `DestinationsNavigator` that you can mock from your previews.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations

Comment: Ok, well `DestinationsNavigator` is an interface, so you can create something like `object MockNavigator : DestinationsNavigator { ... }` and use that in your previews.

Comment: Its documentation actually says exactly that:
*It is meant as a dependency inversion wrapper to make Composables that depend on it be testable and "preview-able"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use This pattern

```
@Composable
fun VerifyScreen(
    email: String,
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator
) {
    VerifyScreenContent(
        email = email,
        navigator = {
            //...
        },
        navigator2 = {
            //...
        },
        navigator3 = {
            //...
        },
    )
}

@Composable
fun VerifyScreenContent(
    email: String,
    navigator: () -> Unit,
    navigator2: () -> Unit,
    navigator3: () -> Unit,
) {
// .. 

}


@Composable
@Preview
fun VerifyScreenContentPreview() {
    VerifyScreen("you@re.awesome", {}, {}, {})
}
```